# Any widget that builds several widgets horizontally and changes lines automatically?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build things like tags from a `List<String>` using `Chip` widget, which would line up from left to right if there is space left horizontally, and if not, render them in the next line. Is there any specific widget that could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap is the widget for you!

```
Wrap(
children:[
*Insert your chips here*
])
```